# Update postgresql with latest security update

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, package-management, postgresql

PostgreSQL announced on the 4th of April [a security update](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1456/) to its PostgreSQL server.

I really want to install that update. But if I run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` the update does not show up.

How can I install this update?

Server: Ubunutu 12.04 and PostgreSQL 9.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These updates are in the repo.](https://lwn.net/Articles/545956/) 9.1.9 is the updated 9.1 release.

```
$ apt-cache policy postgresql-9.1
postgresql-9.1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10
  Version table:
     9.1.9-0ubuntu12.10 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
```

---

I've just noted you claim to be running PostgreSQL 9.2. If you are, getting updates for it is *your responsibility*. 9.2 is not a supported version in the main repos.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up for the 9.2/9.1 difference. Lets change the version to 9.1 then :)